# Asus All In One - Broken screen enter bios and disable on board display?

Tags: all-in-one

I have this all in one that has a broken screen. I'd like to get into bios and disable the on board display and just use the HDMI port for my display. When the all in one reboots it must be defaulting to the on board display port because I don't ever see anything on HDMI port.

Is there anyway I can get into bios and disable the on board display port?

Comment: Probably what you will have to do is unplug the display from the motherboard, then see if it defaults to the hdmi output.

Comment: I do have it unplugged. My plan was to 3D print a case for the motherboard and use a normal monitor.

Comment: I'm not able to get it to boot off a bootable usb stick with Ubuntu on it since I can't see what the default display is doing. It's beyond cracked.

Comment: My limited experience tells me it isn't really possible what you want. Some oldish laptops allowed video output mode selection (Legacy or UEFI - yes, not just for installation modes, I've seen one with this options for video output) where UEFI outputs all POST screens and firmware settings to HDMI. But even if you have one of those, in order to change those settings you would need a functional internal screen.

Comment: Somehow I was able to get it to restore the PC back to factory defaults with the main display hooked up. I have Windows 10 Home on it. I guess now I could do what I was wanting to do which was 3d printing a case for it. The AIO is a Asus ZN242IFD. Intel Core i7 4 Core 2.8ghz. Worth messing with?

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution beyond repairing the broken on-board adapter.

The BIOS/UEFU cannot use HDMI, so there is no way to boot into it.

You need to repair the computer, which might not be worth the expense.